# How to parse a JSON with multiple id's given by FB.API call

Tags: c#, json, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

**EDIT: I "solved" it by not parsing anything and "reading" it by hand like so:**

```
foreach (string key in result.ResultDictionary.Keys)
{
    foreach (string key2 in ((IDictionary)result.ResultDictionary[key]).Keys)
    {
        Debug.Log(key2 + " : " + ((IDictionary)result.ResultDictionary[key])[key2]);
    }
}
```

**Original question below**

I have this snippet:

```
string query = "?ids=";
for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
{
    query += users[i].idFacebook + ",";
}
query = query .Remove(query.Length - 1);
FB.API(query, HttpMethod.GET, responseCallback);
```

Now in the callback I want to parse the JSON I got, but I don't know how to do it, it looks something like this:

```
{
    "facebook-id-1":
    {
        "name":"some name",
        "id":"facebook-id-1"
    },
    "facebook-id-2":
    {
        "name":"some name",
        "id":"facebook-id-2"
    },
    "facebook-id-3":
    {
        "name":"some name",
        "id":"facebook-id-3"
    },
}
```

I tried to use a struct to parse it, but I know I need another struct to read the "upper" nodes, but their names are the id's so I can't create a general struct to work with them

```
struct fbResults
{
    public fbName[] users;
}

struct fbName
{
    public string name;
    public string id;
}
```

This is how I parse the JSON inside the callback:

```
fbResults fbUsers = JsonUtility.FromJson<fbResults>(result.RawResult);
```

I appreciate any help

EDIT: Added more tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I "solved" it by not parsing anything and "reading" it by hand like so:**

```
foreach (string key in result.ResultDictionary.Keys)
{
    foreach (string key2 in ((IDictionary)result.ResultDictionary[key]).Keys)
    {
        Debug.Log(key2 + " : " + ((IDictionary)result.ResultDictionary[key])[key2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm leaving this for anyone who might find it useful, but I hope I don't break any rules, I plan to mark this answer as correct